# Use style trigger to set property of a nested object

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a small polygon written on the large canvas. I want to highlight a polygon when mouse is moving over the canvas. The code is like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
  <Canvas Name="canvas" Height="22" Width="22">
      <Canvas.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="Canvas">
              <Style.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                      <Setter Property="polygon.Stroke" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                  </Trigger>
                  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="polygon.Stroke" Value="Aqua"/>
                </Trigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
      </Canvas.Resources>
      <Polygon Points="11,1 16,6 16,16 11,21" Name="polygon">
              <Polygon.Fill>
                  <SolidColorBrush Color="#EEEEEE"/>
              </Polygon.Fill>
      </Polygon>
  </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

However setter does not see the "polygon".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot use `Setters` like that, if you use this kind of notation the engine will look for an attached property, or if no `Style.TargetType` was set for a property on the type before the dot.

The easiest thing to do is probably applying a style to the polygon itself and using a `DataTrigger` which binds to the `Canvas` so you can trigger on its properties.

```
  <Polygon Points="11,1 16,6 16,16 11,21" Name="polygon">
       <Polygon.Fill>
           <SolidColorBrush Color="#EEEEEE"/>
       </Polygon.Fill>
       <Polygon.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type Polygon}">
             <Style.Triggers> 
                <DataTrigger
                   Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver,
                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                     AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}"
                   Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
       <Polygon.Style>
  </Polygon>
```

Comment: It works, but still only when mouse is over the polygon, not over the rest of canvas. :(

Comment: @Badiboy: Well, as pointed out on another answer you need to set a background on the canvas otherwise there is no hit-test.

Comment: @AngelWPF: If i do not add code that is deliberate most of he time, it may lead to people copy & pasting rather than understanding the concept. Your code for example uses `RelativeSource` in the binding while there would be other ways, so even if the code is not being copied a certain method is being reinforced over the generic concept.

Comment: @H.B., I thought that as you have already explained the answer, the code will help an amature developer to have clearer understanding. I, e.g., was one myself once and struggled a lot when it was only words of explanation as that would make me even more confused. Again sorry to have edited you answer. You can remove it if you want.

Comment: @H.B. I replace the HitTestCore for this user control, so events are rized even if there is no background in canvas. However I'll try to set background...

Comment: @H.B. Shure, the background really solve the issue. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try `EventTrigger`, because other kinds of triggers you could only use in templates or styles. And we already know that Style.Trigger doesn't allow your scenario. So here is working example for you:

```
<Canvas Name="canvas" Height="22" Width="22">
    <Polygon Points="11,1 16,6 16,16 11,21" Name="polygon">
        <Polygon.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="brush" Color="#EEEEEE"/>
        </Polygon.Fill>
        <Polygon.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="brush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                        <ColorAnimation From="#EEEEEE" To="Aqua" Duration="00:00:00.01" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="brush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                        <ColorAnimation From="Aqua" To="#EEEEEE" Duration="00:00:00.01" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Polygon.Triggers>
    </Polygon>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: You could do the same thing with a normal trigger (`Trigger.EnterActions` & `Trigger.ExitActions`), the point is that this is an animation which works differently. Also, your example no longer triggers on the canvas but the polygon itself.

Comment: For EnterActions/ExitActions you need a property IsMouseOver which is a part of IInputInterface. But neither Canvas nor Polygon has its implementation.

Comment: Canvas is transparent, so routed events MouseEnter/MouseLeave will not fire. You need to specify some background for it, at least almost transparent.

Comment: It seems that "RoutedEvent" will work on Polygon only when the mouse will be over polygon, because it's routed from parent to child if both of them are under the event point...

Comment: @invisible: That the canvas in the example is transparent is besides the point, and both Polygon and Canvas have IsMouseOver, so what are you talking about?

Comment: agree, my fail, there is IsMouseOver

Answer (score -2):

It's looking for a property of the Canvas called 'polygon', which in turn has a property called 'Stroke'. You need to use TargetName if you want the setter to target a different object.

```
<Setter TargetName="polygon" Property="Stroke" Value="#EEEEEE" />
```

Comment: I tried this. But "TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter."

Comment: Egg on face. I always forget that little restriction.