# Check property value using eventTrigger?

Tags: wpf, eventtrigger

Is there a way to check a property value using EventTrigger? I would be happy if I could use a regular trigger but it is not a control template:

```
<Polygon Grid.Column="1" Name="fan" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Height="12" Width="12" 
         Points="6,6 4,6 2,5 1,6 2,7 4,6     6,6 6,8 5,10 6,11 7,10 6,8    6,6 8,6 10,7 11,6 10,5 8,6    6,6 6,4 5,2 6,1 7,2 6,4" 
         Fill="Black" Margin="5,8,10,5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Polygon.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Polygon.RenderTransform>
    <Polygon.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SomeEvent">
            <!--I want a StoryBoard here, but only if Polygon's width = 100 (for example) -->
        </EventTrigger>
    </Polygon.Triggers>
</Polygon>
```

Comment: I believe this was solved here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764415/how-to-give-the-condition-for-eventtrigger

Comment: Yes I saw that post, but due to specific task it's not usable for me, I've just found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965409/use-style-trigger-to-set-property-of-a-nested-object