# Changing the background of a button in a DataGrid if the row is selected - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datagrid, styles

I have a datagrid which contains a template column which holds a few buttons.
I need the color of these buttons to change from black to white when the row is selected.
Although I am not sure how can I reach "DataGridRow.IsSelected" from the buttons setters.

Here is what I tried and didn't work:

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=DataContext}"
                                Command="{Binding ViewModel.OnRemoveDirectoryClick, ElementName=Root}">
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="Button.Background">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="../../Images/menu_delete.png"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="DataGridRow.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Button.Background">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="../../Images/menu_delete_white.png"/>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Thanks ahead,
Yotam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found that I needed to use DatatTrigger with a relative source to DataGridRow

```
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="Button.Background">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="../../Images/menu_delete.png"/>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Button.Background">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../../Images/menu_delete_white.png"/>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
```

An additional and perhaps more elegant way I found to tackle this problem was using a template which contains rectangle with white filling which takes the button's background as the opacity mask.

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="DataGridButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid  Style="{x:Null}">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Mask" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Opacity="{StaticResource NormalOpacity}" Style="{x:Null}"
                   OpacityMask="{TemplateBinding Background}" Fill="White" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this style as `Resource`

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="YourButtonName"
                    Value="YourColor" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately this did not work for me, however luckely this produced an error (targetname property cannot be set on a style setter) which led me to an article with a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965409/use-style-trigger-to-set-property-of-a-nested-object