# Setter for inheritance DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, inheritance, datatemplate

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443600/is-there-a-way-to-use-data-template-inheritance-in-wpf) theme. But not understand how to create a Setter in the inheritance `DataTemplate`.
My code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="base">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayString}" x:Name="PART_DisplayString"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="stage">
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource base}">
    <ContentPresenter.Style>
      <Style>
        <Setter TargetName="PART_DisplayString" Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{Binding Path=DisplayString, StringFormat=Stage {0}}"/>
      </Style>
    </ContentPresenter.Style>
  </ContentPresenter>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="room">
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource base}">
    <ContentPresenter.Style>
      <Style>
        <Setter TargetName="PART_DisplayString" Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{Binding Path=DisplayString, StringFormat=Room {0}}"/>
      </Style>
    </ContentPresenter.Style>
  </ContentPresenter>
</DataTemplate>
```

and I get an error **Name "PART_DisplayString" is not recognized.**

Comment: What happens if you get rid of `TargetName="PART_DisplayString"`? I don't think it's supposed to work that way anyway.  The comments at the bottom of this post seem to agree: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965409/use-style-trigger-to-set-property-of-a-nested-object]

Comment: I showed light version `DataTemplate` I have a lot more in it `TextBlock`. Access to them is I get to `x:Name`