# wpf styling a RadioButton with Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to build a template for a `RadioButton` like which changes when selected.

```
<RadioButton GroupName="NewTabButons" Content="{Binding TabTitle}"
             Background="{StaticResource CanvasBackgroundColour}"
             Command=... CommandParameter=...>
    <RadioButton.BorderBrush>...</RadioButton.BorderBrush>
    <RadioButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TabTextColourActive}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Border Height=... Width=... Padding=... VerticalAlignment=...
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderThickness="0 0 0 10"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource Text-Light}" />
                </Border.Style>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource TabTextChevron}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </RadioButton.Template>
</RadioButton>
```

When selected, I want to change the background of the `Border`, as this is the visual element that makes up the control.

I have put the trigger on the `ControlTemplate` in order to trigger on the property `IsChecked`.  However, this means I can't style the `Border` from within the trigger (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7965739/4456875).

If I put the trigger on the Border, I can't get the `IsChecked` property as there is no such thing on a `Border`.

How should a `RadioButton` be templated if you need to trigger on `IsChecked`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a Name for a border

```
<Border x:Name="RadioBorder" Height=... Width=...
```

and it will be accessible from template triggers

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
    <Setter TargetName="RadioBorder" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Trigger>
```

---

the source of problem is that RadioButton Background set explicitly

```
Background="{StaticResource CanvasBackgroundColour}"
```

when I removed it and set Background in style (like this)

```
<RadioButton.Style>
     <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CanvasBackgroundColour}" />
     </Style>
</RadioButton.Style>
```

trigger for IsChecked has worked without changes in template